# Setting style on/in UserControl without having to define MergeDictionary?

Tags: wpf

I'm looking to set a style on some UserControls that's kept in a resource dictionary at the base of my project tree.  The only way I've found to do so is below by defining MergeDictionary in the resources to link in the xaml file with styles.  I'd prefer to not have to put this same code on every single control that needs this style though.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TestApp.Screens.Sub.Details"
    ...
    Style="{DynamicResource BottomContentUserControl}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../../GeneralStyles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the styles to the ApplicationResourceDictionary or you could add them to your App.xaml file so that they will be applied throughout your application.